# Может ли jQuery отследить хэш ссылку?

Tags: jquery

Если хэш ссылка `http://adress.com/#page10`, то можно ли это отследить jQuery и поменять определенному div z-index?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(location.hash == '#page10') {
    $('#some_div').css('z-index',50);
}
```

Comment: спасибо! но это работает при обновлении страницы, а у меня динамика(((

Comment: В этом случае надо отслеживать не изменение hash, а событие перехода по ссылки с hash. Вроде очевидно...

Comment: Уважаемый! Это очевидно только Вам, как специалисту! =) 

а мне это не так очевидно, и можно подробней?

Comment: Куда уже подробнее? Там же куча вариантов. Например,

`
<a href="#page10" id="page10">page10</a>


$("#page10").click(function() {
  $('#some_div').css('z-index',50);
 });
`